# Dot (.) symbol automatically added when pressing the space key 2 or more times

Tags: keyboard

I have seen many times when I type in WhatsApp and press the space key 2 or more times, a period symbol is automatically added. But after I press backspace once, pressing space many times won't add the symbol.

How to remove that automatically added period (.) symbol in WhatsApp and other applications?

Comment: My theory is that this seems like a function of auto-correct by the keyboard you are in. Auto correct could include punctuation rules. I have seen auto-correct to be superceded if an "edit" is initiated via backspacing and undos. Look into the active rules within "Language and Input" for your keyboard on the device.

Answer (score 3):

That is not only on WhatsApp. It is everywhere when you double click space bar, a dot will occur. You need to configure it with your keyboard settings on Android, or simply reset your keyboard settings.

Comment: Thanks i found a option in preference-->Double space full stop when i switch to off that option my problem is solve